# How do I change the "Read More" text

Tags: i18n-l10n

I have to say I feel embarrassed but after several hours of unsuccessful trials and fruitless research I am resigned to ask for help to the community.

6 months ago I have changed the **Read More** text link to **More information**. Now I am asked to roll back to **Read More** and I can't find out how I made it the first time. I am sure I did not override any function in the theme and almost sure I did write any PHP code.

I believe I have done something with the internationalization module because I have now both strings **Read more** and **More information** in the `buit-in interface` textgroup.

So how can I map the Read more link text to a given entry in the `built-in interface`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, if you did it with code you probably edited settings.php and did something like:

```
$conf['locale_custom_strings_en'][''] = array(
  'Read More' => 'More information',
);
```

You would have to remove that line from the array.

There are a billion ways to do it via code, though, To be safe, you should search for the string "More Information" in all of the sites/ files to be safe.

If you didn't do it with code, there is a decent chance you used the [String Overrides](http://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) module, and did it via the UI.  If so, delete that entry.

If this is related to a view, then you should poke through the settings for that view (don't forget the master and all additional displays).  Look for a link field, and check the "Text to display" option.

If not, poke around the field settings for your content types, eg admin/structure/types/manage/page/fields, and see if you set it there.

Comment: The change might also have been made in a node preprocess function

Comment: @Clive, yeah, I thought of that but since the OP didn't think it was a code change, I didn't want to go through all of those possibilities.  Most of the "how to I change this text" questions, blog posts, etc, point to how to do it in settings.php or throug String Overrides.

Comment: Yeah fait point, if it was done in code I guess there are loads of places it could've happened thinking about it

Comment: The full text search saved me. I actually had changed the node template (should have checked this first). Thank you guys.